# PowerShell: Search all property values

Tags: powershell

How can I search *all* the properties of a single object for a given string?

Say I have the following command output:

```
get-aduser jtest -properties *

DistinguishedName : CN=jtest,CN=Users,DC=confederationc,DC=on,DC=ca
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Justus
Name              : jtest
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : f4d31d45-0505-433e-9442-152419e75d26
SamAccountName    : jtest
SID               : S-1-5-21-2138664166-620177494-281947949-184391
Surname           : Test
UserPrincipalName : jtest@confederationcollege.ca
...output truncated
```

How can I search for any property that contains the string "jtest"?

I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Can't you use `-Filter` and put all the properties you want to search in a OR expression? Or may this help: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/active_directory__powershell_remoting-9/23301/find-properties-that-contain-specific-text-string

Comment: You mean you want to find all attributes that `jtest` has or do you want to find all the possible attributes that _any_ AD user object can have? If it's the first you can simply do `-Properties *` if its the later you need to query the Schema.

Comment: `Get-ADUser` by default returns only a subset of possible user attributes. (the ones youy show in your output). For querying other attribs, you need to specify these using the `-Properties` parameter. To see all, use `-Properties *` as @SantiagoSquarzon commented.

Comment: @endo64 But I want to search *all* the properties of an object, so specifying them all in ORs would be way too cumbersome. I just used the above as an example, in reality there are hundreds of properties.

@Theo Thanks, but I'm aware of `-Properties *`. I just used the above as an example to not overwhelm with the number of properties.

I think maybe I didn't make the question clear enough, sorry. I want to search *all* the properties of any given object. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always findstr (case insensitive), but the result is only text.  This is a common question.

```
get-aduser jtest | findstr /i jtest

Name              : jtest
SamAccountName    : jtest
UserPrincipalName : jtest@confederationcollege.ca
```

This doesn't work in all cases, but it does for registry entries.  This can match against most property names or values.  It depends on what "$_" converts to as a string.  Generic pscustomobjects work.  It won't work for the get-aduser example (the object converts to a distinguishedname string).

```
get-itemproperty hkcu:\key1 | ? { $_ -match 'foo' } # or 'emspace'


value1       : 17
emspace      : foo bar
refcount     : {255, 255}
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\key1
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER
PSChildName  : key1
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry


get-itemproperty hkcu:\key1 | % { "$_" }  # showing string conversion

@{value1=17; emspace=foo bar; refcount=System.Byte[]; PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\key1; PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER; PSChildName=key1; PSDrive=HKCU; PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry}
```

Comment: You'd be able to convert this result to a hashtable using `ConvertFrom-StringData`. Something like `get-aduser jtest | findstr /i jtest | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'`.

Comment: Thanks @js2010. I was hoping there was a native PS solution, but this looks like the best bet.

Comment: And thanks @RoadRunner! I didn't know about ConvertFrom-StringData. That's very useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the hidden `psobject` memberset on any object in PowerShell to access its underlying properties programmatically:

```
foreach($user in Get-ADUser jtest){
  foreach($property in $user.psobject.Properties){
    if($_.Value -like '*jtest*'){
      "Property '$($_.Name)' has value '$($_.Value)'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A little more complex than I was looking for for shell usage, but good to know for scripting.